# DVSC connector with GitHub done but not able to create branch from Jira

Tags: github, jira

I have been able to create the DVSC connector with GitHub and my repositories have got synced in Jira following the link: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Linking+Bitbucket+and+GitHub+accounts+to+JIRA . I want to create a branch in one of my repositories in GitHub from Jira. I think it can be done using Development tools option from GitHub. But I am not able to see the Development Tools option for any of my issues. I have checked the permissions and they are fine. I am using Jira Server(on premise version).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the branch creation for GitHub is still not supported, although, they have an improvement request opened for this matter (refer the URL below). I strongly suggest to vote on this request in order to expedite its resolution.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-35175

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished using a plugin. See the [Github App plugin for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.osowskit.jira.github.app/overview)

Comment: OMG! Finally what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: @Mike feel free to provide feedback in a GitHub issue : https://github.com/osowskit/atlassian-github-app-addon/issues